# Integrating an even function on a symmetric interval that equals to zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So I find this integral very interesting since the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2-a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$ is an **even function** you expect the result to now be non-zero when you integrated it over a symmetric interval right?

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^2-a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=0$$

But for this particular integral that is not the case,

First, rewrite the expression to integration by parts form that is set $u=x^2-a^2$ and $dv=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$

From which $du=2xdx$ and $v=\tanh^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$ rearranging the whole thing we get $$-2\int_{-1}^{1}\tanh^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}})xdx$$ the left-hand side vanished since integrating from -1 to 1 its equal to zero

Now since $-2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}})=\ln(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}+1)-\ln(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}})$

Which equals $$\ln\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x}-x}{\sqrt{a^2+x}+x}$$

Then, $$\int_{-1}^{1}\ln\frac{(\sqrt{a^2+x}-x)}{(\sqrt{a^2+x}+x)}xdx$$ which is simply if $s=x$ then $ds=dx$ which gives $$\int_{-1}^{1}\ln\frac{(\sqrt{a^2+s}-s)}{(\sqrt{a^2+s}+s)}ds$$ from this you can see easily that this equals to $\ln{(a^2)}$-$\ln{(a^2)}=0$

Now I’m wondering if there are many more functions like this?

Comment: Hard to believe that the integral is zero. Suggest you try evaluating it with Wolfram Alpha, to check. Also, try graphing the function.

Comment: What is the reason for the last substitution $x=s$?

Comment: @Bubba I did yes, I thought of re-expressing the whole $$-2\tanh^{-1}{(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2})}$$ I believe that is my first mistake

Comment: @Ramanujan to get rid of the x thing and made it more simply

Comment: I don't think this is correct. How does $x dx$ turn into $ds$?

Comment: I assume the differential of x is dx, right?

Comment: If $a<1$ then the integrand is positive everywhere in $[-1,1]$, so hard to see how the integral could be zero.

Comment: I’d guess that there is a specific value of $a$ that makes the integral over $[0,1]$ zero. Then, because the function is even, the integral over $[-1,1]$ will also be zero.

Comment: @AshtineV . The substitution $s=x, ds=dx$ is totally gratuitous. You get $s\,ds$ not $ds$. You dropped a variable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there seems a mistake in the derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really go through your calculations (I suspect it only works for specific choices of $a$, or possibly not at all; double check all your calculations), but it is definitely possible for an even function to have zero integral over a symmetric interval. Consider a function $\phi:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ (assumed RIemann-integrable over every compact interval... or for simplicity just say it is continuous), and suppose that for some $b>0$, we have $\int_0^b\phi(x)\,dx=0$.

Now, we define the function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ as $f(x)=\phi(|x|)$. Then, $f$ is an even function, and
\begin{align}
\int_{-b}^bf(x)\,dx&=2\int_0^bf(x)\,dx\tag{$f$ is even}\\
&=2\int_0^b\phi(|x|)\,dx\\
&=2\int_0^b\phi(x)\,dx\\
&=0.
\end{align}
However, if you're dealing with positive even functions, then no, the integral is always going to be positive.

As a concrete example, take $f=0$, which obviously has zero integral. Another example is to take $f(x)=\cos x$, an even function which satisfies $\int_0^{\pi}\cos x\,dx=0$ (positive and negative parts up to $\pi/2$ cancel out), so $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos x\,dx=0$, and so on.

Comment: This is the first thing I suspect, I think I made a mistake somewhere with my steps but that mistake just get me wondering about this question. The graph can’t have zero integral anywhere for every values of a

Comment: @AshtineV right, your calculation is definitely wrong (because for the limiting case $a=0$ you're just integrating $|x|$ from $-1$ to $1$ which should give a positive number). I suggest you go over every step you made slowly and do the algebra/integration by parts/substitution carefully and be sure to justify every step.